# How can I store data from API in my activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting json data from api then I convert it to a data class using gson 
What I want is :

1 - store the data to reduce the Http requests to the api with the ability to refresh the data
2 - access the data in another activity

I have tried :

1 - pass the data with Intent to the second activity and it's works but when I get back to the main activity I must do another Http request to get the data

2- use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to store the data class object but `onRestoreInstanceState` never get call when I back to the main activity

```
class carView : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "Volly"
    lateinit var dataObject : Bundle
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_view)

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getData()
        }else{
            dataObject.putSerializable("all_cars",savedInstanceState.getSerializable("all_cars"))
        }
        Log.i(TAG," the object is $dataObject")

        recycler_View.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler_View.adapter = mainAdapter(dataObject.getSerializable("all_cars") as Cars)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestoreInstanceState")

        val Object = savedInstanceState?.getSerializable("all_cars") as Cars
        recycler_View.adapter = mainAdapter(Object)
        Log.i(TAG,"Object is ${Object}")
    }
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState")
        val Object = intent.extras?.get("Extra_object") as Cars
        outState?.putSerializable("all_cars",Object)

    }
    fun getData(){
        val url = "http://192.168.1.100:5000/car/getCars"
        val oRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    val result = gson.fromJson(response,Cars::class.java)
                    Log.i(TAG,"the list ${result}")
                    dataObject.putSerializable("all_cars",result)

                }catch (e : JSONException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { err ->
                Log.i(TAG,"err {$err}")
            }){

        }
        oRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(20* 1000 , 0 , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
        val requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requestQ.add(oRequest)

    }

}
data class Cars(val cars:List<CarModel>?) : Serializable
data class CarModel(
    var _id     : String,
    var name    : String,
    var ownerId : String,
    var image   : String
//    var profile: List<imageData>
) : Serializable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Shared Preferences**.

**Example for Kotlin to save information**:

```
val name = getName()
val surname = getSurname()
val saved = isSaved()

val preferences = getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val preferencesEditor = preferences.edit()
preferencesEditor.putBoolean("saved", saved)
preferencesEditor.putString("name", name)
preferencesEditor.putString("surname", surname)
preferencesEditor.apply()
```

**Example for Kotlin to get information**:

```
val preferences = getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val saved = preferences.getBoolean("saved", false /*Default value*/)
```

Comment: It's only one of the other methods to solve your problem, you can use database or files to save your data.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the data from the API store the data in shared preference and in onCreate write the code to get the data you stored previously using shared pref.Now whenever your activity starts check if the data is available in shared pref if it is available send it to the second activity if it is not available then make the API call.